# Hazelcast with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

I was looking into hazelcast and found some good integrations with springboot.  However, I want to understand if that is it or if we need the hazelcast servers to make a prod ready implementation. Can some one point out a resouce where I can look at the setup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run Hazelcast in either an embedded mode -- where the Hazelcast cluster nodes are colocated with the application clients -- or in a client-server mode, where the Hazelcast cluster is separate from the application clients.   Both can be used for production.   Embedded is generally easier to get up and running quickly.  Client-Server might be better if you want to be able to tune and scale the cluster independently of the application clients.

See https://support.hazelcast.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004441586-What-s-the-difference-between-client-server-vs-embedded-topologies-

The only change in application code to switch between architectures is the line of code that instantiates the client

```
Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(); // creates an embedded client instance
```

while

```
Hazelcast.newHazelcastClient(); // creates a server client instance
```

I'd recommend the reference manual as the definitive source on configuration options and how to achieve what you need

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/

Comment: Is it safe to use hazelcast embedded mode without an additional  db layer. I have a requirement where I need to store  data only for a dat and the data is not sensitive. My application will be deployed on 2 instances. Is the embedded mode suitable for this case

Comment: If you have 2 instances, then partitions from each instance will be backed up to the other (assuming the default configuration of 1 async backup isn't changed).  So you  can lose one node with no data loss.   If "data is not sensitive", then running without a persistence layer may be acceptable.  But if a node goes down, and you don't have a standby ready to go into service right away, then you will be running unprotected and at risk for the loss of all data.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go through the reference manual. But I would also like to share how I have deployed the hazelcast instances on production servers and how I have used it.

Step 1: Create a xml config file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <hazelcast
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config https://hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.9.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <group>
    <name>"your_service_name"</name>
    <password>"service_password_chosen"</password>
</group>

<properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.partition.count">83</property>
</properties>

<management-center enabled="true" update-interval="3">--url--</management-center>
<network>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="false"/>
        <aws enabled="false"></aws>
        <tcp-ip enabled="true">
            <member>"internal ip of your instance"</member>
            <member>"internal ip of other instance</member>
        </tcp-ip>
    </join>
</network>

<map name="*.ttl3hr">
    <max-size policy="USED_HEAP_PERCENTAGE">3</max-size>
    <eviction-policy>LFU</eviction-policy>
    <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
    <backup-count>0</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>1</async-backup-count>
    <read-backup-data>true</read-backup-data>

    <time-to-live-seconds>10800</time-to-live-seconds>  <!--3 hours-->
</map>
```

Step 2: Add `@EnableCaching` and add a bean in the file annotated with `@Configuration`.

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance) {
    return new com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager(hazelcastInstance);
}
```

Step 3: Then you can annotate your methods with `@Cacheable` annotation.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "your_cache_name")
public POJO foo(Parameter1 parameter1,
        Parameter2 parameter2) {
    return pojoRepository.findByParameters(parameter1, parameter2);
}
```